# Calling shared preference from static object in another activity?

Tags: android

I've come across an issue with trying to append a settings preference string onto another string I have.

Currently I have:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    public static final String USER_LOGIN = "https://example.com";

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    myFunction(USER_LOGIN);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve this with:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    public static final String USER_LOGIN = "https://" + preferences.getString(SettingsFragment.USER_SITE, "");

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    myFunction(USER_LOGIN);
}
```

However, Android Studio is telling me "non-static field 'preferences' cannot be referenced from a static context". How would I be able to reference this field?

Comment: just put preferences variable static..

Comment: @JackTurky Thanks! When I do this however I get the following error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign them inside `onCreate` :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String USER_LOGIN;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        USER_LOGIN = "https://" + preferences.getString(SettingsFragment.USER_SITE, "");

        myFunction(USER_LOGIN);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since "SharedPreferences preferences" is a Object's member, it can not be used by a static member. So change :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

to

```
static SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried your suggestion, but I now get:

error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

Is your function in the same activity? If yes try not to pass the static var?
Instead access it directly in the "myfunction".. 
I see no point to call that way and make it static at the same time.

Comment: The function is from an API library for the site

Comment: Why u need to have your variable static? that i don't see.